# Does LMD and ClamAV have any packages for sending reports to a monitoring console?

Tags: malware, monitoring, clamav

I currently have about forty Ubuntu Servers (mostly 18.04 and 20.04) that I am installing ClamAV and maldetect on so we have at least some monitoring for malware on the systems. What we will likely do is set up an email address (virus-scans@mycompany.com) to collect and view all the reports periodically to check for any viruses or malware.

One question I had was whether these products have the ability to be monitored from a remote central server. If I have a Windows PC or Ubuntu Desktop, can I have that system go and poll for the latest scans, or have the monitored servers send me XML or JSON data in some sort of email?

The idea would be that I would like to have one system that I go to and can examine all the servers from a central console instead of having to log into each one, or open 40+ emails each day.

Comment: You could set up "remote logging" on each of the 40+ clients (read `man -k syslog` on each kind of client) to send their logs to a central log server. With such a wide range of versions, there are sure "improvements" among them. There are log monitoring packages. It's easy to log LMD and ClamAV results to system logs (`man logger `)

Comment: @guiverc My question is really related to the LMD and ClamAV packages and is not Ubuntu rev-dependent. I provided my range of Ubuntu versions installed simply to demonstrate that if someone has a solution for ANY of the versions up to and including 20.04, I am very interested in hearing about it.